# VBA Compare Cell Value in two different workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to compare two cell value in two different workbook. I debugged and find `x.Range("A" & rw).Value = y.Range("N" & re).Value` this part is not working. I also tried  assigning parameters and using `Cells(rw, "A")`, still not working. Can some one please help?

```
Option Explicit

Sub findcell()

Dim rw As Integer, re As Integer

Dim extwbk As Workbook, twb As Workbook
Dim x As Worksheet, y As Worksheet
Dim Rng As Range


Set twb = ThisWorkbook
Set extwbk = Workbooks.Open(".........xlsx")
Set x = twb.Worksheets("ABC")
Set y = extwbk.Worksheets("DEF")




    For rw = 2 To x.UsedRange.Columns("A").Rows.Count

      For re = 3 To y.UsedRange.Columns("N").Rows.Count

         If x.Range("A" & rw).Value = y.Range("N" & re).Value And x.Cells(rw, 1) <> Null Then
         ' If use below line, it is working
        'If x.Cells(rw, 1) = 45032 And y.Cells(re, 14) = 45032 Then
            MsgBox x.Cells(rw, 1).Value
            MsgBox y.Cells(re, 14).Value
         Exit For
         End If       

      Next re

    Next rw


extwbk.Close savechanges:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: What `x.Cells(rw, 1) <> Null` means??? What are you trying to do?

Comment: x.Cells(rw,1) mean x.Cells(rw,"A") is not empty, tested this part is ok.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with david that the problem might be

```
x.Cells(rw, 1) <> Null
```

Instead try

```
Not IsEmpty(x.Cells(rw, 1))
```

Comment: I tried IsEmpty(x.Cells(rw, 1)) still no work, I changed the data to another columns which contains text, it worked using exactly same codes, I think it is text number format issue.

Comment: "x.Range("A" & rw).Text = y.Range("N" & re).Text" this worked, thank you guys.